# What will >_ command do in bash

Tags: bash, macos, shell, command, command-prompt

I saw >_ in bash shell icon in mac and was wondering what it will do.

I tried performing the command but I was not able to figure out what happened. My command prompt silently came again.

It should be doing something, that's why it is in the icon for terminal.

Do anyone know what it does and can it be used for something?

Comment: It's just an image of a prompt followed by the cursor. However if you try it, it's redirecting standard output into a file named `_`. Since there is no output to redirect, all it accomplishes is creating (or recreating) an empty file with that name.

Comment: yah it is but it is also a valid command, try it out.

Comment: Yes Cyrus you are correct....

Comment: Are you sure its not `>$_`?  That would be a little more useful (`$_` is the rightmost argument to the previous command).

Answer (score 1):

Running `>_` will successfully run (nothing), redirected to a file named `_`. It's not terribly *useful*, but that's what it does. The most useful empty redirection I've seen is to empty the contents of a file with it:

```
> /var/log/app.log
```

which, if `app.log` is not open by another process, will result in /var/log/app.log being empty.